# _CrtSetAllocHook - empty filename and lineNumber arguments

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

_CrtSetAllocHook is used to register a function with the following declaration:

```
int MyAllocHook(int allocType, void* userData, std::size_t size, int blockType, long requestNumber,
const unsigned char* filename, int lineNumber);
```

I have noticed that for allocations which come from my code I get empty filename and lineNumber arguments. How to fix that ?

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>

int MyAllocHook(int allocType, void* userData, std::size_t size, int blockType, long requestNumber,
const unsigned char* filename, int lineNumber)
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    _CrtSetAllocHook(MyAllocHook);
    void* ptr = malloc(128);
    if (ptr)
    {
        free(ptr);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I set a breakpoint in MyAllocHook.

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Please see Edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a go to definition on "malloc" and see if it gives you the

```
#define malloc(s)          _malloc_dbg(s, _NORMAL_BLOCK,` __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

line in

If not add a "#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC" before any includes (better yet add _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC as part of the preprocessor symbols in the project settings).